# Database Logon failed

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, crystal-reports

This exception is occuring on client Pc while crystalreports are working fine on production Pc

```
 CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LogOnException: Database logon failed. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Database logon failed.
at       CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass.GetLastPageNumber(RequestContext pRequestContext)
at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.GetLastPageNumber(ReportPageRequestContext reqContext)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ConvertDotNetToErom.ThrowDotNetException(Exception e)
at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.HandleException(Exception exception)
at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.GetLastPageNumber(ReportPageRequestContext reqContext)
at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.PrintToPrinter(Int32 nCopies, Boolean collated, Int32 startPageN, Int32 endPageN)
at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(Int32 nCopies, Boolean collated, Int32 startPageN, Int32 endPageN)
at CButtonTestForm.frm_sale1.print(Int32 op1) in D:\CButton\CButtonTestForm\frm_sale1.vb:line 221
at CButtonTestForm.frm_sale1.cmd_print_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\CButton\CButtonTestForm\frm_sale1.vb:line 1253
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button,    Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr   wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

[image]

When I click on print button, it gives the error Logon Failed:

```
    Function print(ByVal op1 As Integer) As Integer
    adpt = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT orderdetail.sr, orderdetail.prid, orderdetail.sp, orderdetail.qty, orderdetail.total FROM orderdetail where OrderID=" & cmbinv.Text, cn)
    ds = New DataSet()
    adpt.Fill(ds, "orderdetail")
    rpt.SetDataSource(ds)
    ' Dim Report1 As New saleinv
    '   Report1.DataDefinition.FormulaFields.Item("Text7").Text = txttoken1.Text
    rpt.SetParameterValue("Token", txttoken1.Text)
    frmsalerpt.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
    rpt.PrintToPrinter(1, True, 0, 0)
 End Function
```

Comment: are you sure their account has permission to query your data?

Answer (score 0):

Fill your database server information like this:

```
CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo crLogonInfo;
crLogonInfo = this.crystalReport.Database.Tables[0].LogOnInfo;
crLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = SystemConfiguration.DBInstance.SQLServerName;
crLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = SystemConfiguration.DBInstance.SQLUserID;
crLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = SystemConfiguration.DBInstance.SQLPassword;
crLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = SystemConfiguration.DBInstance.SQLDatabaseName;
this.crystalReport.Database.Tables[0].ApplyLogOnInfo(crLogonInfo);
```

Comment: Also, more detailed information about the cause of the login failed error will be written to the SQL Server error log. This information is not returned to the client for security reasons.